# Login with different Login ID's for native mobile application using JMeter

Tags: automated-testing, performance, load-testing

I know for different parameters I have to use a CSV DatasetConfig and create a .csv file, with the email id and password separated by a comma.

For native mobile apps, we are using HTTPS Test Script Recorder, which records the actions I am doing. Using the recording, I am able to create the script for only one user, but I want multiple users to log in and log out.

I want to create a flow like:

1. First user logged in - > logout
2. Second user logged in -> logout

Answer (score 0):

Just substitute recorded values with the variables from the CSV file, for example you have recorded something like:

[image: JMeter credentials]

And you have [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) like:

[image: JMeter Variables From CSV]

You can just replace the recorded values with the relevant [JMeter Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) like:

[image: JMeter CSV file]

See [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) article for more information on parameterizing your JMeter tests using CSV files.

Comment: Instead of HTTP Request my username and password are stored in
HttpAuthorizationManager
I created the CSV Dataset Config in my Recording Controller and pass those values  in my HttpAuthorization Manager with ${}
and now if I run it 
results are displayed only in console and not in View Results Tree

Comment: In case of [Basic HTTP Authentication](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-http-basic-authentication-jmeter) you should see `Authorization` header under [Request tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhue6.png) with the value of `Basic` followed by [Base-64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded `username:password` pair

Comment: HTTP Authorization Manager is under my Recording Controller which is under my thread Login

Is It because of the Debuuger sampler

I am getting java.lang.ArrayStoreException in my command prompt whenever I run this Script In GUI